# Recursion to print the sum of first ten numbers using a single like if else in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, recursion

```
def ad(a): 
    return a+ad(a+1) if a<10 else return a
ad(1)
```

Returns an error that tells invalid syntax
any thoughts?

Comment: `return a+ad(a+1) if a<10 else ad(1)` ?

Comment: Doesn't it point to where the invalid syntax is?

Comment: The valid syntax is `return [expression]`, where `[expression]` can in turn have the form `[expression] if [condition] else [expression]`, so the second `return` is wrong. Also I suspect the `ad(1)` at the end of the second line was an error, since it is invalid syntax and would cause infinite recursion anyway.

Comment: @Rakesh Please avoid answering questions in comments.

Answer (score 1):

`def ad(a): 
    return a+ad(a+1) if a<10 else a
ad(1)`

Your code is not working because you have written return statement in return statement.
Explanation of my code is pretty simple:
when a reaches 10 it returns 10 otherwise sum of its number and ad(next number).

```
a(10) = 10  
a(9) = 9 + a(10) = 9 + 10 = 19  
a(8) = 8 + a(9) = 8 + 19 = 27
```

...

```
a(1) = 1 + a(2) = 1 + 54 = 55
```

Comment: Please provide useful information why this salves the problem, not just the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have some typos.

```
def ad(a):
    return a+ad(a+1) if a<10 else ad(1)
```

but here is logical errors too.

Update: probably you expect this:

```
def ad(a):
    return a + ad(a + 1) if a < 10 else 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked if we have any thoughts.  My thought is that it doesn't make much sense to write a function that only works on one case of a generalized problem.  If you're only calculating for 10, you might as well just pre-calculate the answer and wire it to return 55.

I'd suggest a more general implementation, which calculates the sum from the passed argument down to zero, or just returns the argument if it is negative:

```
def sum_to(x):
    return x + sum_to(x-1) if x > 1 else x

print(sum_to(0))    # => 0
print(sum_to(10))   # => 55
print(sum_to(20))   # => 210
print(sum_to(-10))  # => -10
```

(In reality though, I'd use the direct calculating formula `x * (x + 1) / 2` rather than recursion.)